Some values are shown 100 bigger in Powerbi Table
My data is showing in transform data as: MAD 19:$22 160 and Opex ($9 356,78)
enter image description here
But when trying to make a table out of it,it somehowe mutlplied my Opex line by 100 from ($9 356,78) to ($935 678), but not the MAD 19 (which stayed  $22 160)
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
Any insight on how to solve this?
I tried to change formatting, looked into the excel data and can't figure out what is wrong here

you can try to replace the comma. pls check if this works for you


I think your comma has been interpreted as a thousand separator rather than a decimal one. I can't replicate your problem, but you should look into your local settings :

If your PBI is not in French, change it back.
Hope this helps
